# OAuth compliance and legacy applications migration

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

Pretty common case that arises when you try to incrementally migrate the current heavyweight enterprise application to modern architecture.

Can the migration strategy (at least the 1st step) for such application look like **Use OAuth Resource Owner Password Credentials grant: issue and use the access token instead of authentication cookie and here you go**?

Here are the details:

We have an existing ASP.NET enterprise application and a requirement to introduce token-based security for its REST HTTP services. The existing implementation uses a conventional login page that exchanges username/password for an authentication cookie – that needs to be preserved for keeping legacy pages working.

We ended up with the following: in addition to issuing the auth cookie the login page will return the access token to the client and all the subsequent REST HTTP services would be secured via that token only (token is sent in Authorization header). That is a [Bearer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) token because no proof of possession of a cryptographic key by a client is implied.

Can we advertise that the new scheme is OAuth 2.0 compliant at least from the [Resource Owner Password Credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) (section 4.3 of the specification)? If not, what else needs to be done to make a statement that the new implementation (that uses the access token) is OAuth 2.0 compliant?

At this moment we aren’t interested in extending this scheme to support authorizing 3rd party applications. In other words, we aren't interested in supporting other [grant types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3).

I understand that this question has some marketing flavor but deep dive into the specification didn't produce a concise and comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your suggestion is what the Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC) grant was designed for. There are basically two parts to an OAuth 2.0 flow wrt. the Client i.e. a) how the Client "gets" a token and b) how the client "uses" the token. Those two legs are independent. In the ROPC grant the Client still "gets" the token in a legacy way (marked as "for migration purposes only" in OAuth 2.0) but as you indicate the Client will "use" the token against the Resource Server in a completely OAuth 2.0 compliant way.

So in your case the protocol flow between Resource Server and Client and thus the implementation of that is standard OAuth 2.0 and can be advertised as such. Moreover it won't change even if the Client starts using different grants to get the token.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for